# Animating counting number with gradient background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gradient

I am trying to make a counting animation on numbers with a gradient background. However, it does not seem to be possible to make this work if the numbers have a gradient background, with my current script.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```js
var alreadyPlayed = false;

jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
  var scroll_pos_test = 300;

  if (y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test && !alreadyPlayed) {
    alreadyPlayed = true;
    console.log('300');
    jQuery('.count').each(function() {
      var jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
      jQuery({
        Counter: 0
      }).animate({
        Counter: jQuerythis.text()
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
          jQuerythis.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.counter-p {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(63, 77, 179, 1) 0%, rgba(63, 179, 120, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter-div">
  <span class="counter-header">Example1</span>
  <span class="counter-p">
        <span class="count">34</span>%
  </span>
  <span class="counter-ending">Example</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There's an extra `}` in your code - is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: Can you update the snippet so that it demonstrates the problem?  At the moment, there's not enough to go on.  e.g. does it work if they don't have a gradient?

Comment: That was just a typo, and I am not exactly sure what you mean? Yes it seems to be working without the gradient.